# Making a reservation button

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I'm making a class reservation website and having trouble with creating the button.
I would like to customer to insert two details session into two textboxes, session type "class" or "workshop" and date & time and they will be able to see that information from the DataGridView displayed.

Once they hit the "Reserve" button the button will run a query where it'll add the chosen session from Session table to Reservation table. However my code executes with no errors but does not update the "Reservation" table.

here's my code:

```
OleDbConnection myConnection = GetConnection();

    OleDbCommand cmd = myConnection.CreateCommand();
    string query = "select COUNT(*) from [Yoga-Session] where [session type] = '" + txt_type.Text + "' and duration = '" + txt_datetime.Text + "';";

    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, myConnection);
    myConnection.Open();
    int rows1 = (Int32)command.ExecuteScalar();

    if (rows1 >= 1)
    {
        cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select session_id from [yoga-session] where [session type] = '" + txt_type.Text + "' and duration = '" + txt_datetime.Text +"';",myConnection);
        int classId = (Int32)command.ExecuteScalar();

        cmd = new OleDbCommand("select client_id from client where name = '" + Session["[name]"] + "';", myConnection);
        int clientID = (Int32)command.ExecuteScalar();

        string query1 = "insert into reservation (session_id, client_id, client_name) values ('" + classId + "','" + clientID + "','" + Session["[name]"].ToString() + "');";

        cmd = new OleDbCommand(query1, myConnection);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Response.Write("Reservation successful");

        Response.Redirect("reservation.aspx");

        myConnection.Close();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int classId = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
int clientID = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

You need to use `cmd.ExecuteScalar()` to get `session_id` and `client_id` values. `ExecuteNonQuery` returns you no of rows affected by the SQL query.

**Also** see what @Sherantha pointed out.

Comment: hey, I have made the changes to classId and clientId but its no difference :(

Comment: Take `session_id` and `client_id` values and execute insert statement in SSMS (Sql Server Mgmt Studio). See if that updates the record you want. If not then you data does not match and there's nothing wrong in ADO.NET code.

Answer (score 0):

`ExecuteNonQuery()` is not for SELECT commands. To get a field value from SELECT command we need to use `ExecuteScalar()`.

Try replacing;

```
int rows1 = (Int32)command.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: hey, I've  made the changes but still getting no results @Irshad

Comment: What is the result for `rows1 `?

Comment: Result of this line. Debug it.`int rows1 = (Int32)command.ExecuteScalar();`

Answer (score 0):

You should use query1 instead of query.

```
    string query1 = "insert into reservation (session_id, client_id, client_name) values ('" + classId + "','" + clientID + "','" + Session["[name]"].ToString() + "');";

    cmd = new OleDbCommand(query1, myConnection);// not query but query1
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Response.Write("Reservation successful");
```

**PS:** Use sql data reader to select data.

```
cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select session_id from [yoga-session] where [session type] = '" + txt_type.Text + "' and duration = '" + txt_datetime.Text +"';",myConnection);
SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
int classId = 0;
while (rdr.Read())
{
    clientID = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["session_id"]);
}
```

Comment: hey, Thanks for pointing out that silly mistake lol, however I'm still getting no results :(

Comment: I think the way you try to select classID and client ID is the problem. see my edit and do the same to select client ID and session name.

Comment: once I applied your code I can't seem to use ClassID and ClientID in query1, I get "use of unassigned loacal variable" in both variables @sherantha

Answer (score 0):

Just a small headsup before I compose my real answer (because I don't have rep to comment)

Firstly: Use Prepared Statements. They help immensely in reducing errors from typing SQL queries, as well as a way to prevent SQL Injection Attacks in real-world situations.

Secondly: While not really needed in most database types, it is recommended that a naming convention is strictly uniform in your code.

Well aside from that, I will get to the real answer now.

Looking at the code, I am assuming that `classID` and `clientID` are integers, but in your code, it looks like they are parsed as strings due to the ' ' characters. Do not use the characters when inserting integers.

EDIT: is [session type] meant to be [session_type]?

Comment: hmm i'll change me code to use prepared statements , thanks for the heads up.. [Session Type] not [Session_type] @aeee98